# How to get all values from a table which includes itself as another value neighbour field at the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.
First table keeps "group_names" with id numbers. Second table keeps "groups_elements" with id numbers and group_id numbers next to element_name. Third table keeps relations between group_elements which includes element_id, sub_element_id.
I wish to get concat group_name, element_name and element_id numbers sub_elements numbers.
Here is sqlfiddler link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44f63

And i wish to get such result:

```
Solid Soil  5,6,7
Liquid Oil  8,9,10
```

I am using MySQL and PHP.

Comment: you like the result on 1 column or separate column?

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat and `JOIN` to link table. First thing you should do is to show us what you have done...

Comment: i mean 1st column is Solid, as the second and third Soil and (5,6,7)

Comment: How to concat values in records, not in fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so

```
SELECT  CONCAT(g.group_name,' , ',e.element_name)
, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  er.sub_element_id)
FROM groups g
JOIN elements e ON(g.id = e.group_id)
JOIN element_subelement_relation  er ON(er.element_id= e.id)
GROUP BY g.group_name, e.element_name
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44f63/34)

**Edit from comments**

```
SELECT  CONCAT(g.group_name,' , ',e.element_name) `group_elements`
, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  er.`sub_element_id`) `ids`
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN elements e ON(g.id = e.group_id)
LEFT JOIN element_subelement_relation  er ON(er.element_id= e.id)
GROUP BY g.group_name, e.element_name
HAVING group_elements IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY g.group_name
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44f63/47)

Comment: So how could i include unrelated group and element names and order by group names?

Answer (score 1):

using `group_concat()`

```
SELECT g.group_name, group_concat(sub_element_id) as items
FROM elements e INNER JOIN element_subelement_relation er
ON e.id = er.element_id INNER JOIN groups g
ON g.id = e.group_id
GROUP BY g.group_name
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44f63/21

Comment: This is not giving the element name for each group and op also need the element name too

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid thank you. I saw a simple explaination on group_concat on http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/ and got it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply join and use group_concat on the sub ids:

```
select
  concat(g.group_name, ' ', e.element_name) as name,
  group_concat(sub_element_id order by sub_element_id) as sub_elements
from elements e
inner join groups g on g.id = e.group_id
inner join element_subelement_relation r on r.element_id = e.id
group by name
order by sub_elements, name;
```

The SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44f63/31.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try these:

```
SELECT g.group_name, e.element_name, concat(g.id,",", e.id,",",esr.id) as ID
FROM element_subelement_relation esr
LEFT JOIN elements e ON(esr.element_id = e.id)
LEFT JOIN groups g ON(e.group_id = g.id)
```